Number Theory: Fermat's little Theorem and Wilson's Theorem
I am currently studying Fermat's Little Theorem and Wilson's Theorem, and I am encountering a problem that I cannot seem to solve. The problem states:
If $p$ is an odd prime, then
$$
\sum_{a=1}^{p-1} \frac{a^{p-1} - 1}{p} \equiv \frac{(p-1)! + 1}{p} \mod p
$$
To tackle this, I first applied Fermat's Little Theorem, which tells us that for any integer $a$ not divisible by $p$:
$$
a^{p-1} \equiv 1 \mod p
$$
This implies that $p$ divides $$ a^{p-1} - 1, $$ leading to the conclusion that:
$$
\frac{a^{p-1} - 1}{p}
$$
is an integer. Next, I utilized Wilson's Theorem, which states that:
$$
(p-1)! \equiv -1 \mod p
$$
Thus, we have:
$$
(p-1)! + 1 \equiv 0 \mod p.
$$
Consequently, I have shown that:
$$
\sum_{a=1}^{p-1} (a^{p-1} - 1) \equiv (p-1)! + 1 \mod p.
$$
However, I am unsure how to proceed from this point to fully prove the original statement. Any guidance or insights into how to move forward with this proof would be greatly appreciated!

The result you want to prove is equivalent to equation (48) of this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1912.06652

Set $F\left(a\right)=\frac{a^{p-1}-1}{p}$. We start by showing that for all $a,b$ with $p\nmid a,b$ $$F\left(ab\right)\equiv F\left(a\right)+F\left(b\right)\mod p.(*)$$Indeed $$F\left(ab\right)-F\left(a\right)-F\left(b\right)
$$$$=\frac{\left(ab\right)^{p-1}-1}{p}-\frac{a^{p-1}-1}{p}-\frac{b^{p-1}-1}{p}$$$$
=\frac{\left(a^{p-1}-1\right)\left(b^{p-1}-1\right)}{p}\equiv0\mod p$$by Fermat's little theorem (as $p\nmid a,b$). Next, we apply $\left(*\right)$ iteratively to get $$\sum_{a=1}^{p-1}F\left(a\right)\equiv F\left(\left(p-1\right)!\right)\mod p.$$Set $D:=\frac{\left(p-1\right)!+1}{p}$. By Wilson's theorem, $D$ is an integer. Note that as $p$ is odd, $(-1)^{p-2}=-1$, $(-1)^{p-1}=1$, so $$F\left(\left(p-1\right)!\right)=F\left(Dp-1\right)=\frac{\left(Dp-1\right)^{p-1}-1}{p}
=\frac{\sum_{k=0}^{p-1}{p-1 \choose k}D^{k}p^{k}\left(-1\right)^{p-1-k}-1}{p}=\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}{p-1 \choose k}D^{k}p^{k-1}\left(-1\right)^{p-1-k}
\equiv{p-1 \choose 1}D\left(-1\right)^{p-2}\equiv-\left(p-1\right)D\equiv D$$$$=\frac{\left(p-1\right)!+1}{p}\mod p$$and we're done.
